# ESLint: Promise returned in function argument where a void return was expected

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, typescript-eslint

I have multiple routers in my server, and every time I run my ESLint script, the same error gets thrown for every single one of them. The error in question is this one:

`error  Promise returned in function argument where a void return was expected  @typescript-eslint/no-misused-promises`

The code of my routers is like this one:

```
import { getAllCards } from '../controllers/CardsController';
import express from 'express';
import { isAValidToken } from '../controllers/TokenController';
import { errorCallback } from '../controllers/ErrorController';
const router = express.Router();

router.get('/', isAValidToken, async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const cards = await getAllCards();
        res.json(cards);
    } catch (error: any) {
        errorCallback(error, res);
    }
});
```

TokenController:

```
import jwt from 'jsonwebtoken';
import { API_SECRET, API_SECRET_REFRESH, TOKEN_EXP, REFRESH_TOKEN_EXP } from '../constants/constants';
import { Request, Response, NextFunction } from 'express';

async function verifyAnyToken (token: string, secret: string): Promise<unknown> {
    return await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        jwt.verify(token, secret, (error) => {
            if (error != null) {
                reject(error);
            } else {
                resolve(token);
            }
        });
    });
}

async function verifyToken (token: string): Promise<unknown> {
    return await verifyAnyToken(token, API_SECRET);
}

export async function getTokenFromRequest (req: Request): Promise<string> {
    const token = req.body.token || req.headers['x-access-token'] || req.headers.authorization || req.params.token;
    return await getNormalizedToken(token);
}

export async function isAValidToken (req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction): Promise<void> {
    const token = await getTokenFromRequest(req);
    await verifyToken(token);
    next();
}
```

Since the error is pointing where the `isAValidToken` function is called in my router, that seems to be the problem, either with the call itself or with something else that I'm not aware of.

Comment: I don't know typescript well but you shouldn't use unknown and you shouldn't await for promise if you return in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`async / await` is syntactic sugar for a Promise. So by calling `async await new Promise()` you are effectively resolving a Promise with another Promise. Structure your controller to look more like your router, using a try/catch block without declaring new Promises.

```
async function verifyAnyToken (token: string) {
 try {
  const decoded = await jwt.verify(token, API_SECRET);
   console.log(decoded);
  } catch(err) {
    console.log(err) 
  }; 
}

export async function getTokenFromRequest (req: Request) {
 try {
  const token = //
  if(token){
    const normalizedToken = await getNormalizedToken(token); // 'return await ...' will just return a promise and not the normalizedToken value
    console.log(normalizedToken);
  } else {
    console.log('No token')
  }}
  catch(err) {
   console.log(err)
  };
}

export async function isAValidToken (req: Request, res: Response, next: Function){
 const token = await getTokenFromRequest(req);
 await verifyAnyToken(token);
 next();
}
```

The `verifyToken()` function is redundant. It's just an async function calling another async function from another async function. Which adds unnecessary layers of promises and callbacks.